# What is the correct way to type a React component class that has no props?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

The top level component in a React project by definition won't have any props passed to it. What is the appropriate way to type this when using Typescript?

I've been using the following as a model recently, but perhaps there's a simpler way?

```
interface AppState {
    ...
}
class App extends React.Component<{},AppState> {
    constructor(props: never) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            ...
        }
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: I would suggest you start using functional components. :-)

Comment: Unless you are doing something else in the constructor (which you probably should not be), you can just omit it entirely.

Comment: @ExplosionPills I am also initializing my state in the constructor

Comment: @SangamRajpara I am using state in my components so I believe I need to use a class

Comment: You can initialize state via the state property in the class definition... `state: AppState = { ... }`

Comment: @codedude we have a hook `useState` for using state in function components. https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate

Comment: @LindaPaiste I've been playing around with functional components over the last month since your comment - they're clearly superior. :) Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Constructors were mainly used to declare your `state` or bind your class methods. Nowadays, constructor is called implicitly if you omit it, no declaration needed. Hence once you omit it, it may lead you to wonder how to bind or declare state.

You can declare outside you state property, and likewise you can bind your methods declaring them as arrow functions:

```
class App extends React.Component<{},AppState> {
    // state can be declared outside from constructor
    state: AppState = { name: '' }

    // arrow function avoid the need to bind
    onChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
      this.setState({name: e.target.value})
    }
}
```

This way you can write a cleaner syntax when using Class based Component.

Comment: Does this also apply to components with props?

Comment: yes, it does. it doesn't matter if your class receives props or not.